# Filling empty list with zero vector using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So here is the thing.
I have a list of lists and some of the list are empty... but if it is not empty.. all the list are of fix length.. the length which I dont know..
For example

```
  for feature in features:
     print len(feature)
```

This will print either 0 or length k.

I am trying to write a function

```
  def generate_matrix(features):
     # return matrix
```

Which returns a numpy matrix.. with empty rows replaces with zero vector.
Is there a way to do this efficiently?
I mean... I don't want to loop thru to find the shape of matrix and then again loop thru to generate row (with either np.array(feature) or np.zeros(shape)..

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use np.zeros?

Comment: Why don't you want to loop through the list twice?  Have you done any timings?

Comment: @ballsatballsdotballs: I can use np.zeros.. but how do i find the dimensions  of zero vec apriori.

Comment: Do all of the non-empty features have the same length?

Comment: @ballsatballsdotballs Yepp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I didn't realize that all of the non-empty features were the same length.  If that is the case then you can just use the length of the first non-zero one.  I added a function that does that.

```
f0 = [0,1,2]
f1 = []
f2 = [4,5,6]

features = [f0, f1, f2]

def get_nonempty_len(features):
    """
    returns the length of the first non-empty element
        of features.     
    """
    for f in features:
        if len(f) > 0:
            return len(f)
    return 0

def generate_matrix(features):
    rows = len(features)
    cols = get_nonempty_len(features)
    m = np.zeros((rows, cols))
    for i, f in enumerate(features):
        m[i,:len(f)]=f
    return m

print(generate_matrix(features))
```

Output looks like:

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]]
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to "loop thru to find the shape of matrix and then again loop thru to generate row (with either np.array(feature) or np.zeros(shape)"

Comment: @yangjie Ok but why?  He has two options: making all of his lists the same length by padding them with zeros (which seems like a bad idea since you are changing your input lists), or finding the shape and then creating an ndarray with them.  Both of those require looping through the `features`, anyway.

Comment: The length fetching loop could stop at the 1st nonzero value.  The OP claims length is either 0 or k.